Как очистить содержимое файла с помощью python?
У меня есть код:
i = "Какой нибудь текст"
f = open('note.txt', 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
f.write(i)

Как удалить текст записанный в файле?

убрать + из второго аргумента?

Варианты использования режимов:

r - Открывает файл только для чтения. Указатель файла помещается в начале файла. Это режим "по умолчанию".
rb - Открывает файл в бинарном режиме только для чтения. Указатель файла помещается в начале файла. Это режим "по умолчанию".
r+ - Открывает файл для чтения и записи. Указатель файла помещается в начало файла.
rb+ - Открывает файл в бинарном режиме для чтения и записи. Указатель файла помещается в начале файла. Это режим "по умолчанию".
w - Открывает файл только для записи. Перезаписывает файл, если файл существует. Если файл не существует, создает новый файл для записи.
wb - Открывает файл в бинарном режиме только для записи. Перезаписывает файл, если файл существует. Если файл не существует, создает новый файл для записи.
w+ - Открывает файл для записи и чтения. Перезаписывает существующий файл, если файл существует. Если файл не существует, создается новый файл для чтения и записи.
wb+ - Открывает файл в бинарном режиме для записи и чтения. Перезаписывает существующий файл, если файл существует. Если файл не существует, создается новый файл для чтения и записи.
a - Открывает файл для добавления. Указатель файла находится в конце файла, если файл существует. То есть файл находится в режиме добавления. Если файл не существует, он создает новый файл для записи.
ab - Открывает файл в бинарном режиме для добавления. Указатель файла находится в конце файла, если файл существует. То есть файл находится в режиме добавления. Если файл не существует, он создает новый файл для записи.
a+ - Открывает файл для добавления и чтения. Указатель файла находится в конце файла, если файл существует. Файл открывается в режиме добавления. Если файл не существует, он создает новый файл для чтения и записи.
ab+ - Открывает файл в бинарном режиме для добавления и чтения. Указатель файла находится в конце файла, если файл существует. Файл открывается в режиме добавления. Если файл не существует, он создает новый файл для чтения и записи.

То есть ваш файл и так будет очищен и перезаписан, если вы хотите вообще его отчистить можно записать пустую строку ("")
Подробнее можно прочить по ссылке
https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-open/
